# Topex/Poseidon satellite data reading and extracting

Tags: satellites, nasa

I'm trying to figure out how to read and extract Topex/Poseidon satelite altimeter data from the Physical Oceanography Distributed Active Archive Center (PO.DAAC). Link to product: https://podaac.jpl.nasa.gov/dataset/PODAAC_MGDR.
The products are L2 MGDRB. They provided a software written in ANSI C language which according to their README file is an interactive dump program and asks for a starting and ending record of the pass file. It lists the header records followed by one or more data records.
The question is: Are there any other simpler tools to read and extract data from these files or do I need to learn C programming?
I've already tried using GIS and SNAP but with no results.